# how to solve $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \over \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} g(x)$?

Tags: limits

how to solve $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \over \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} g(x) $ when $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} g(x) = +\infty$?

for example what are the solutions of $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x \over \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} 2x $ or $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x \over \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x^2 $?

I think we can't use the L'hopital rule because ${\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \over \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} g(x)} \neq \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} {f(x) \over  g(x)} $ . (not sure)

So please tell me how to solve these kinds of problems and which theorems we use must use.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, we can use L'Hopital

Comment: ${\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) \over \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} g(x)}=\frac \infty \infty $ will not work here but $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} {f(x) \over  g(x)}$ might

Comment: @MarkViola it is not meaningful to divide infinity by infinity

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\lim_{x\to\infty} 2x}{\lim_{x\to\infty} x}$$ doesn't make sense, because neither the limit in the numerator nor that in the denominator exists.  The rule that the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits only holds when the latter limits exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky territory. It is true that the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{2x}
$$
both exists and is equal to $1/2$. However, we can't split the limit of a quotient into a quotient of limits. This is because
$$
\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty}x}{\lim_{x \to \infty} 2x}=\frac{\infty}{\infty} \, ,
$$
which is undefined. $\infty/\infty$ is as meaningless as $\text{yellow}/\text{blue}$. In fact, some mathematicians prefer not to write
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}2x = \infty \, ,
$$
instead saying that 'the limit does not exist'. What those mathematicians are trying to emphasise is that infinity is not a number. In fact, saying that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}2x = \infty
$$
is just a shorthand for saying that as $x$ gets larger, $2x$ also gets larger and larger. To be more precise, the value of $2x$ is unbounded. We are most certainly *not* saying that $2x$ is approaching the number infinity.

---

We can use L'Hopital's rule to evaluate
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{2x}
$$
but this is needlessly heavy handed. $x/(2x)=1/2$ for all $x$, and so the limit simplifies to
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \, .
$$
Once again, we don't care about $x=\infty$, whatever *that* means.

Comment: OK, but what about $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x \over \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x$. Is the answer 1 or undefined?

Comment: @ElsaHejazian When we write $$\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} x}{\lim_{x \to \infty} x} \, ,$$ we have to evaluate the numerator and the denominator individually first. With this in mind, can you answer your own question?

Comment: With this in mind, it's undefined. but the numerator and the denominator are exactly the same and they are not zero (denominator is not zero) so why we can't say that it's 1? Why we have to evaluate denominator and numerator individually first?

Comment: @ElsaHejazian In general, when we write $a/b$, we have to work out what $a$ is, and then work out what $b$ is. Sometimes there are rules that allow us to ignore this. For example, $$\frac{a+b}{c}=\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c} \, .$$ However, *by definition*, $$\frac{a+b}{c}$$ means 'work out what a plus b is, and then divide this number by $c$'. In the example we are dealing with, there is no way to simplify $$\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty}x}{\lim_{x \to \infty}x} \, .$$ We can't write it as the limit of a quotient, since that rule only applies in a certain cases.

Comment: The quotient law for limits states that $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x \to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x \to a} g(x)} \, ,$$ *provided that both limits exist and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x) \neq 0 \, .$*

Comment: And writing that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \infty$ is just another way of saying that the limit does not exist because the value of $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches $a$, is unbounded.

Comment: @ElsaHejazian Hi Elsa. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much